# AvalonDock: Documents switch using Keyboard controls Ctr+Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, keyboard, avalondock

I have an `AvalonDock` in my solution with fully `MVVM` integrated. Everything works fine till now,
I used to switch between documents by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>] and it works as expected.

I have Binded the `ActiveContent` to a property in my `ViewModel` and when ever it switch the document it sets properly.

**Issue:**
Now i have undocked my all documents and tried to switch between documents using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but this time its not working,

**Whats happening:**
I have a break point at my `ActiveContent` Property, when i switch the document with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it get hit with correct document first, after that it again hits with the previous `ActiveContent` and set back the focus to the old one as a result the selected document with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> not getting the focus.

I hope some one can give me a solution.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem... I am having the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ababeel This issue is corrected in latest builds I believe. I haven't follow up much as our requirement changed.